# Get sources maps to work when the are in a different directory

Tags: typescript, webstorm

How do you get sources maps to work when the are in a different directory from the ts file? Seems bby default it expect it to be in the same directory.

I am using WebStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source maps can be located anywhere - if the correct `//# sourceMappingURL` comment exists in the generated .js file, the debugger normally can map source file to the generated one. This works for me at least

Comment: where is the best place for this in the ts file?

Comment: The TypeScript compiler will insert it as the last line of the generated JavaScript file when using the `--sourcemap` command line option.

Comment: @Douglas thx but it doesn't point to the ts file: sourceRoot":"","sources":["Common.ts"].  the ts file is in **../ts**

Comment: so it comes up blank in the debugger. I don't like having all the files in my ide in the same directory

Comment: what command do you use to compile your ts files? I have a relative paths generated in "sources" if the original ts file and generated map are in different folders. Like:

Comment: "file":"Foo.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../utils/Foo.ts"]

Answer (score 0):

###### Lets say that the two (2) statements, *following this line*, are true:

---

1. Your source files (aka your `.ts` files) are in a dir named `src/`
2. Your source-maps are in a directory named `map/`

---

So first, you need to configure where your source code is. You may think you have done this with other settings, and you probably have, but you need to use the `tsconfig.json` setting that tells `TSC` how to configure the source maps it emits. You want them to emit with the correct path back to your source code, therefore; you want to use the setting under this text:

###### *Assuming the opening statments in this answer are true, the following setting should be used with `"src"` assigned to it:*

#### `"sourceRoot": "src"`

What sourceRoot does is it assigns the correct value to the source maps sourceRoot field:

If you can, examine a source map right now:

When you look in the source map you will see a JSON config like this:

```
    // Inside a source map you have the following (give or take
    // some properties)
    {
        "version": 3,
        "file": "index.js",
        "sourceRoot": "", // <- it adds the correct value here
        "sources": [ "" ],
        "mappings": "uCACCo..." // Base64 References (there should be a very long list of these.
    }
```

- **FIRST:** If you first build your project without the `"sourceRoot"` configuration at all, your source maps should contain the json example above (or something that looks very much like it).
- **THEN:** If you then add the `"sourceRoot"` configuration, and point it to your TypeScript source files directory, you should notice that your source maps will look much closer to the example below, which tools like the debugger need to locate the source files.

```
    {
        "version": 3,
        "file": "index.js",
        "sourceRoot": "../src", // <- should change this directory value
        "sources": [  // <- should change this array-field
            "../src/some-file.ts", 
            "../src/some-other-file.ts" 
        ],
        "mappings": "uCACCo... " // This may or may not change
    }
```

---

Then you need to point the debugger to the directory where your source maps are, using the following:

#### **`"mapRoot": "map"`**

I have always needed to configure these two settings together to get my debugger working properly. If you are in a situation where your source-maps wound up somewhere-else (for me it was when I had to upload a project to a server, which then I added a VM to the server, and a container in that, and to satisfy the VM, docker & my project, stuff just wound up where I didn't want it, but these settings helped me get things up & running.